# Installing python package in virtualenv without using pip or easy_install

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, easy-install, pyexiv2

I'm trying to install [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/overview.html) in a virtualenv. Unfortunately it's an old package and neither pip nor  easy_install seem to support it. I installed it on my non-virtualenv python just fine, by running the windows installer on the pyexiv download site, but I can see no easy way to install it it a virtualenv. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot! 
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Windows installers](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/download.html) are basically just executable zip files with some installer code at the front. They can be expanded using any unzipping utility like `unzip` in Git Bash/Cygwin/MingW32, Winzip, 7-Zip File Manager, etc. Once unzipped, just copy the resulting `pyexiv2` folder to your virtualenv's `site-packages` folder, and you should be all set. The installer also includes two `.dll` files in a folder called `$PLUGINSDIR`, but I'm not sure where they should go, or if they're part of the installer. Don't do anything with them for now, and test the module to see if everything works properly. If it complains, hopefully the error message will give enough detail to figure out where it's looking for the files, and you can put them there.

Good luck!

Comment: Oh neat, I never realized that's what the installers were doing. I copied the folder to the site-packages but it gives me an error when I try to import pyexiv2: `ImportError: No module named libexiv2python`.